# Rails ActiveRecord relation between 2 models have same column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, model, relation

I have 2 models - Person, EmailSubscription

**people** Table

```
class CreatePeople < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :people do |t|
        t.integer :store_customer_id
        t.string :email
    end
  end
end
```

**email_subscriptions** Table

```
class CreateEmailSubscriptions < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :email_subscriptions do |t|
        t.integer :email_subscription_type_id
        t.integer :store_customer_id
    end
  end
end
```

**Relation**

```
Person.store_customer_id = EmailSubscription.store_customer_id
```

**How I did**

```
class Person < ApplicationRecord
  def email_subscription
    EmailSubscription.where(store_customer_id: store_customer_id).first
  end
end

class EmailSubscription < ApplicationRecord
  def person
    Person.where(store_customer_id: store_customer_id).first
  end
end
```

Are there any better solutions?

Thank you.

Comment: Why is the last one doubled? Was it supposed to be a `class Person` and `class EmailSubscription`?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't put `person_id` in the `people` table.

As the primary key of `people` is person's id.

So for the people table:

```
class CreatePeople < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :people do |t|
      t.string :email
    end
  end
end
```

And to make the relation happen you should implement the `email_subscribtions` table with a foreign key of people table:

```
class CreateEmailSubscriptions < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :email_subscriptions do |t|
      t.integer :email_subscription_type_id
      t.references :person, foreign_key: true
    end
  end
end
```

Check [here](https://medium.com/@where_is_x/activerecord-t-references-foreign-key-and-belongs-to-e58cebc79493) for rails references.

And in the models you just add:

```
class Person < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :email_subscription
end

class EmailSubscription < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :person
end
```

And this will simply give give you the power of `acrive_record` associations:

```
@person.email_subscription

@email_subscription.person
```

Answer (score -1):

You did not explicitly state why you need to add such a method to your model class

```
def email_subscription
  EmailSubscription.where(person_id: person_id).first
end
```

I want to believe `email_subscription` `belongs_to person` and `people has_many: email_subscriptions`
If what you want is to access or get an email_subscription that `belongs_to` a particular person, then `self.email_subcriptions` will return the subscription belonging to the current person, for email_subscription class you could add `self.person`. Perhaps you could use a scope rather than a method but I feel you can call this directly in the controller too.

Comment: No. your suggestion will work for Person.id = EmailSbuscription.person_id. It is not for my case.

Comment: You should probably add more details to your question.